# What is definition of robust image segmentation?

Tags: image-segmentation

I read the term "robust (image) segmentation" a lot in literature but I couldn't find a definition of the term. Based on the literature, I can guess the term may mean that its segmentation result is accurate enough for further analysis with the result, regardless of all different image conditions that are possible in a given application field. I want to hear from experts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robustness is generally considered to be good (acceptable) performance under uncertainty.  Generally, this uncertainty is "noise" of some description but it could be some other form of uncertainty.

[This paper by Antoine Vacavant](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-56414-2_6) says:

> the definition of robustness by Peter Meer as “An estimator is
> considered robust only when the estimation error is guaranteed to be
> less than what can be tolerated in the application”.

I doubt you'll find a definition of the term or, rather, I suspect you'll find many definitions of the term. Possibly as many definitions as there are authors.

In [robust control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_control), the idea of robust is different:

> Probably the most important example of a robust control technique is
> H-infinity loop-shaping, which was developed by Duncan McFarlane and
> Keith Glover of Cambridge University; this method minimizes the
> sensitivity of a system over its frequency spectrum, and this
> guarantees that the system will not greatly deviate from expected
> trajectories when disturbances enter the system.